# Why is there an Option.get method

Tags: scala, scala-collections, api-design

Why is the method `get` defined in `Option` and not in `Some`?

One could apply pattern matching or use `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap`, `getOrElse` which is preferred anyway without the danger of runtime exceptions if `None.get` is called.

Are there really cases where the `get` method is so much convinent that it justifies this? Using the `get` method reminds me to Java where "I don't have to check for null because I know the var is set" and then see a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I guess it is for migration from `Java`. Sometimes it's useful in `REPL`. I'd like to have a compiler option to treat `.get` as error.

Comment: In the same vein: why is there a List.head method? Interestingly, even Haskell has it, resulting in a runtime error when applied to an empty list.

Comment: To get even closer to the core of the question: why are there exceptions (or other things that make a function partial)?

Comment: Did anyone mention https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7262?

Answer (score 6):

Option.get is occasionally useful when you know, by reasoning that isn't captured by the type system, that the value you have is not None. However, you should reach for it only when you've tried:

- Arranging for this knowledge to be expressed by your types.
- Using the Option processing methods mentioned (flatMap, getOrElse etc), and none of them fit elegantly.

It's also convenient for throwaway / interactive code (REPL, worksheets etc).

Comment: That's pretty much it. I do think the syntactic overhead for doing this should be higher to be less tempting to newbies who think "dammit, my value is in an `Option`! how can I get it out?! oh, `get`"

Comment: @MyseriousDan - maybe, although it's also the sort of thing you can easily flag up with static analysis tools.

Comment: Sure, but code analysis is a retrospective tool. My goal is to make developers feel guilty about using it in the first place, so that they design their code not to need it. A three-letter word with no guilt-inspiring words in it like `unsafeGet` or `getButThisWillLeadToBugsIPromise` is not a sufficient deterrent, in my opinion. Detecting it doesn't help much if you find 1500 instances of it in your codebase and rearchitecting it to push those errors toward the user will take 5 man-years of work.

Comment: @MyseriousDan well, the downside is that a 30 character name is to the detriment of the legitimate uses -- not sure that's a good trade. My suggestion would be to pick up bad style in regular code peer review sessions -- devs new to Scala will need this anyway, in my experience.

Comment: My point is that the illegitimate uses vastly outnumber the legitimate ones and we should not optimize for the occasional latter case. Someone using `get` needs to feel a pang of guilt when using it to make sure it's really necessary and can't be done more cleanly.

Comment: I agree with MyseriousDan. And IMHO if you can guarantee that the variable is not None, then you should not use `Option` in the first place. If you get the Option from some other function then you (most likely) cannot guarantee that it is not a None (or will change in future implementation)

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt: I agree in general, just that there are a minority of occasions when `get` is still reasonable. I recently wrote some code to return Some(topological sort) of a directed graph, if it had one, else None. Also, some code to break cycles in an arbitrary graph and return an acyclic graph. A third routine ran the cycle-breaking code, then obtained a topological sort. Calling `get` on the result is reasonable, because we can prove that it is safe -- even though the types don't capture that property. (You could represent that in types, but I think it would be overkill here).

Answer (score 2):

**Foreword**

Scala was created with compatibility for the JVM as a target.

So it's pretty natural that `Exception`s and `try/catch` should be considered as part of the language, at least for java interoperability.

With this premise in mind, now to the point of including interfaces that can throw errors in *algebraic data types* (or *case classes* if you prefer).

---

**To the Question**

Assume we encapsulate the `get` method (or `head` for `List`) only in `Some` instance.
This implies that we're forced to pattern match on the `Option` every time we want to extract the value. It wouldn't look pretty neat, but it's still a possibility.

We could `getOrElse` everywhere but this means that I can't signal a failure through the error stack if using imperative style (which is not forbidden in scala, the last time I checked).

My point here is that `getOrElse` and `headOption` are available to enforce a functional style when desired, but `get` and `head` are good alternatives if imperative is a choice fit to the problem or the programmer's preference.

Comment: I don't agree that get and head imply imperative programming, or that getOrElse/HeadOption imply functional programming. That's like saying `if` is not allowed in functional programming, but that simply doesn't follow.

Comment: `if` doesn't return any value, as opposed to `if/else`, so I would assume it's not purely functional, but an imperative control flow element. But I'm not considering too deeply the implications here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *good* reason for it. Martin Odersky added it in [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/cc4427befb91bcdc183008d8a0cc727f0549f55e) in 2007, so I guess we'd need to ask him his motivations. The earlier version had `getOrElse` semantics.

Comment: Martin Odersky didn't add `get` method in this commit. There was already method [`get: A`](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/cc4427befb91bcdc183008d8a0cc727f0549f55e#L1L43). He moved an implementation from `Option` to `Some` and `None`.

Comment: Method `get` is in `Option` since [initial version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/23d2bfbeb21f63d82ed46d5b1b0b85b1ed2f4355/sources/scala/Option.scala).

Comment: ...which does not mean much. `getOrElse` could as well be abstract and independently implemented in `Some` and `None`, or left as is (minus the @inline) and have `get` as a private method.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the [commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/cc4427befb91bcdc183008d8a0cc727f0549f55e) provided. It's kind of obvious why and 
when it is used. The get is used to unbox when you are sure there is `Some`thing in the
`Option`. It would also serve to be an inheritable method where `None.get` Throws an exception and `Some.get` unboxes the contents.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, when your `Option` turns out to be a `None`, there is no recourse and you want to throw an exception.  So, instead of writing

```
myOption match {
  case Some(value) => // use value
  case None => throw new RuntimeException("I really needed that value")
}
```

you can simply write

```
myOption.get // might throw an exception
```

It also makes `Option` *much* nicer to use from Java, in conjunction with `isDefined`:

```
if (myOption.isDefined()) process(myOption.get());
else // it's a None!
```

Comment: A agree it's nicer from Java. However I don't agree with your first argument. If you need to throw an exception then it should be explicit in the code and the exception should have a meaningful message and no the default returned by `Option.get`

Comment: Could go either way.  Often you'll see a chunk of code where a number of exceptions may be thrown only to be caught and wrapped something context-aware higher up the call stack.  Nonetheless, let's not engage in holy wars over exception handling here :)